# Django block inclusion not working. What did I miss?

Tags: django, django-templates

In my `base.html` file I have this:

```
{% block menu %}{% endblock menu %}
```

and in `base_menu.html` I have this:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}    
{% block menu %}
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
... stuff ... 
</div>
{% endblock menu %}
```

I would expect the menu html to show where the initial `block menu` directive is...but it is not including. Did I miss something?

It should be SO easy! :D

Comment: Looks good. Are you sure you're actually loading the `base_menu.html` file and not the `base.html` file in your view?

Comment: I might be misunderstood. I am using this like I would as a php include. Is this supposed to be tied to a view to initiate?

Comment: (ideally this is just a simple include to break up the file)

Comment: It's not a php include, it's inheritance, you're setting up a hierarchy of templates. That's pretty much the *reverse* of a php include.

Comment: That is where I was confused thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django templates do not use inclusion so much as [template inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/templates/#template-inheritance).

The idea is you set up a hierarchy of templates, specializing some common thing. For instance:

- you could have a `base.html` that has some basic page structure, common to all pages of your website.
- you could then have a couple of templates that extend it according to some common layouts. Like `section.html`, `object-details.html`.
- and then build your final templates by extending those. Like `book-section.html`, `author-details.html`, `book-details.html`.

The point is, in your view you include the leaves of your inheritance tree. They only define the details of what goes in the placeholders (blocks) that have been defined higher in the inheritance tree.

Example:

**base.html**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>{{ title }}</title>
    {% block css %}<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">{% endblock %}
</head>
<body class="{% block bodyclass %}{% endblock %}">
    <header>{# TODO: put some logo and banner here #}</header>
    {% block body %}
</body>
</html>
```

**base_2cols.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block bodyclass %}{{ block.super }} two-columns{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
    <nav><ul>{% block menu %}</ul></nav>
    <div id="wrapper"><main>{% block content %}{% endblock %}</main></div>
    <aside>{% block metadata %}{% endblock %}</aside>
{% endblock %}
```

**book.html**

```
{% extends "base_2cols.html" %}

{% block bodyclass %}{{ block.super }} book{% endblock %}

{% block menu %}
    <li>Some menu item</li>
    <li>Some other menu item</li>
{% endblock menu %}

{% block content %}
    <article>
        <h1>{{ book.title }}</h1>
        <p>{{ book.description }}</p>
    </article>
{% endblock %}

{% block metadata %}
    Last updated on {{ book.updated|date:"Y-m-d" }}
{% endblock %}
```

In your view, you'd use `book.html`. It would render a full page with two columns (well, given the right css of course), with the main column containing the title and description, and the aside column having the last updated part.

The whole point is to allow re-use and separation of concerns. The `base.html` concerns itself with the structure of a document. The `base_2cols.html` concerns itself with how to create a 2-column view with a menu. The `book.html` concerns itself with how to render a book, given a place where to put content and another where to put metadata.